# Created life cycle hook event code is not called in Integration environment

Tags: vue.js

The created life cycle hook contains a function which populates data in a drop down. This is the component loaded first in my application. This works when i test it in localhost but not in Integration environment. Suggest a solution for this.

```
//Code snippet
created: function (result) {
            this.loadStores();
        }
```

Comment: Can you define `Integration environment`?

Comment: `created` function will not take any `result` argument.

Comment: How do i define environment in Vue JS ?

Even after removing result, created is not called.

Comment: Check the below link https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/deployment.html